# Detect square in a List of Points

Tags: java, algorithm, point

I want to test if there is a square in a list of Point object or not.

This is my Point class :

```
class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int distanceSquare(Point q) {
        return (x - q.getX()) * (x - q.getX()) +
                (y - q.getY()) * (y - q.getY());
    }
}
```

I can test if four Point is a Square or not :

```
static boolean isSquare(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4) {
        int d2 = p1.distanceSquare(p2);  // from p1 to p2
        int d3 = p1.distanceSquare(p3);  // from p1 to p3
        int d4 = p1.distanceSquare(p4);  // from p1 to p4

        if (d2 == d3 && 2 * d2 == d4) {
            int d = p2.distanceSquare(p4);
            return (d == p3.distanceSquare(p4) && d == d2);
        }

        if (d3 == d4 && 2 * d3 == d2) {
            int d = p2.distanceSquare(p3);
            return (d == p2.distanceSquare(p4) && d == d3);
        }
        if (d2 == d4 && 2 * d2 == d3) {
            int d = p2.distanceSquare(p3);
            return (d == p3.distanceSquare(p4) && d == d2);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

But I didn't found the best way to search the square in a list of Point.

Can you help me !!!

Comment: Are the points that form the square contiguous in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated to also detected rotated squares**

I like Egor Skriptunoff's answer above, but let me try to give
another answer.  I think the complexity is only O(N^2).

**Algorithm**

For any pair of points (P0, P1) (there are N^2 of them), find out
the vector V01 from P0 to P1, and then rotate this vector by 90
degrees (it becomes V12).  Add it to P1, and see if you can find a point 
there? (this can be done by a hashmap lookup -- see more below)  If so
then you have P2, and continue the procedure.

Rotate the vector by another 90 degrees (it become V23), Add it to 
P2, and see if you can find a point there? (Again, by a hashmap lookup)
If so, then you have P3, and continue the procedure.

Rotate the vector by another 90 degrees (it becomes V34).  Add it
to P3, and see if can find a point there? (Again, by a hashmap lookup).
If so, check also if this point P4 is the same as P0.  If so, then
you have just detected a square.

The following diagram illustrates the idea.

[image]

**Data Structure**

If the squares are rotatable, then the x and y coordinates of Point 
must be in floating point (double) and cannot be integer.  Because
a lot of computation will give you irrational numbers (e.g. sqrt(2))

However, a double representation cannot be precise as an integer, 
so we have to be careful
to treat two double numbers that are close enough as the same double
value.  In my code, I use an epsilon as the tolerance that we allow
for "approximate equivalence".  I picked 1E-3 as the epsilon.

```
public class Point2 {
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private final double eps = 1E-3;    
    public double getEps() {
        return eps;
    }
```

And then in all computation regarding `equals()` and `hashCode()`,
make sure you use a "snapped" value of x and y, not their original
double representations. (Graphically you can imagine this like your
graphical editor give you a "snap to grid" feature, with the grid size
being epsilon).  Also you need to be careful that in double reprsentations 
there are positive 0 and negative 0, and you should also treat them as 
the same value.

Something like this:

```
public long getXsnapped() {
    return Math.round(this.getX()/this.getEps());
}   
public long getYsnapped() {
    return Math.round(this.getY()/this.getEps());
}   
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    long temp;
    temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(eps);
    result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
    if (Math.abs(this.getX())>this.getEps()) {
        // include X only if it is larger than eps
        temp = this.getXsnapped();
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
    }
    if (Math.abs(this.getY())>this.getEps()) {
        temp = this.getYsnapped();
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
    }
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Point2 other = (Point2) obj;
    if (Double.doubleToLongBits(eps) != Double.doubleToLongBits(other.eps))
        return false;
    boolean answer = true;
    if (Math.abs(this.getX())>this.getEps()
            || Math.abs(other.getX())>this.getEps()) {
        // compare value and sign only if X of both points are larger than eps
        if (this.getXsnapped()!= other.getXsnapped())
            answer = false;         
    }
    if (Math.abs(this.getY())>this.getEps()
            || Math.abs(other.getY())>this.getEps()) {
        // compare value and sign only if Y of both points are larger than eps
        if (this.getYsnapped()!= other.getYsnapped())
            answer &= false;
    }
    boolean isDebug = false;
    Util.debugPrint(isDebug, "p1 %s; p2 %s: %b (eps is %.9f)%n"
        , this, other, answer, this.getEps());
    return answer;
}
```

Furthermore, each square has four points.  You can add a rule in
your program saying that the four points must be in order as used in 
the algorithm (P0->P1->P2->P3) with the set angular relationship 
(see the algorithm above).  However, you also need to be careful that
the given the same four points there are four options to choose 
the start point. So your Square object code must treat the
following squares specified by these four points as equivalent:

```
P0->P1->P2->P3
P1->P2->P3->P0 
P2->P3->P0->P1
P3->P0->P1->P2
```

This can be done in the constructor of the Square object and always
"canonicalize" the input by 
picking a point with a certain sailent feature 
as the starting point (e.g. pick the point having the lowest x, and
if its x value tie with another point, then pick the point having the lowest 
x and smaller y among the tied pair)

**Test Input 1**

```
-1.4142,    9.8995
-5.6569,   15.5563
1.4142,    9.8995
-1.4142,   14.1421
-2.1213,   14.8492
1.4142,   14.1421
0.0000,   15.5563
-2.1213,   17.6777
7.0711,   11.3137
5.6569,   12.7279
4.2426,   14.1421
6.3640,   10.6066
7.0711,   14.1421
5.6569,   15.5563
1.4142,   19.7990
7.7782,   14.8492
```

**Test Result 1**

```
===== Given a set of following points from file src\detectSquare\inputSet1_45_1_1_0_0.txt =====
1: Point2 [x=-1.4142, y=9.8995]
2: Point2 [x=-5.6569, y=15.5563]
3: Point2 [x=1.4142, y=9.8995]
4: Point2 [x=-1.4142, y=14.1421]
5: Point2 [x=-2.1213, y=14.8492]
6: Point2 [x=1.4142, y=14.1421]
7: Point2 [x=0.0000, y=15.5563]
8: Point2 [x=-2.1213, y=17.6777]
9: Point2 [x=7.0711, y=11.3137]
10: Point2 [x=5.6569, y=12.7279]
11: Point2 [x=4.2426, y=14.1421]
12: Point2 [x=6.3640, y=10.6066]
13: Point2 [x=7.0711, y=14.1421]
14: Point2 [x=5.6569, y=15.5563]
15: Point2 [x=1.4142, y=19.7990]
16: Point2 [x=7.7782, y=14.8492]
===== The following squares have been found =====
1: SquareRotatable [points=[Point2 [x=4.2427, y=14.1421], Point2 [x=5.6569, y=12.7279], Point2 [x=7.0711, y=14.1421], Point2 [x=5.6569, y=15.5563]]]
```

**Test Input 2**

```
0.0000,    0.0000
-0.7071,    0.7071
-1.4142,    1.4142
0.7071,    0.7071
0.0000,    1.4142
-0.7071,    2.1213
1.4142,    1.4142
0.7071,    2.1213
0.0000,    2.8284
```

**Test Result 2**

```
===== Given a set of following points from file src\detectSquare\inputSet2_45_0_0_0_0.txt =====
1: Point2 [x=0.0000, y=0.0000]
2: Point2 [x=-0.7071, y=0.7071]
3: Point2 [x=-1.4142, y=1.4142]
4: Point2 [x=0.7071, y=0.7071]
5: Point2 [x=0.0000, y=1.4142]
6: Point2 [x=-0.7071, y=2.1213]
7: Point2 [x=1.4142, y=1.4142]
8: Point2 [x=0.7071, y=2.1213]
9: Point2 [x=0.0000, y=2.8284]
===== The following squares have been found =====
1: SquareRotatable [points=[Point2 [x=-1.4142, y=1.4142], Point2 [x=0.0000, y=0.0000], Point2 [x=1.4142, y=1.4142], Point2 [x=0.0000, y=2.8284]]]
2: SquareRotatable [points=[Point2 [x=-0.7071, y=0.7071], Point2 [x=0.7071, y=0.7071], Point2 [x=0.7071, y=2.1213], Point2 [x=-0.7071, y=2.1213]]]
3: SquareRotatable [points=[Point2 [x=-1.4142, y=1.4142], Point2 [x=-0.7071, y=0.7071], Point2 [x=0.0000, y=1.4142], Point2 [x=-0.7071, y=2.1213]]]
4: SquareRotatable [points=[Point2 [x=-0.7071, y=2.1213], Point2 [x=0.0000, y=1.4142], Point2 [x=0.7071, y=2.1213], Point2 [x=-0.0000, y=2.8284]]]
5: SquareRotatable [points=[Point2 [x=-0.7071, y=0.7071], Point2 [x=0.0000, y=0.0000], Point2 [x=0.7071, y=0.7071], Point2 [x=0.0000, y=1.4142]]]
6: SquareRotatable [points=[Point2 [x=0.0000, y=1.4142], Point2 [x=0.7071, y=0.7071], Point2 [x=1.4142, y=1.4142], Point2 [x=0.7071, y=2.1213]]]
```

**JUnit Test Program testing `Point2#getXsnapped()` (fragment only)**

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Point2Test {
    private List<Point2> points = new ArrayList<>();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        points.add(new Point2(0.49999999f, 0));
        points.add(new Point2(0.50000001f, 0));
    }
    ...

    @Test
    public void testGetXsnapped() {
        System.out.format("testing xSnapped of two points: %s and %s%n"
                , points.get(0), points.get(1));
        System.out.format("and they are %d and %d respectively%n"
                , points.get(0).getXsnapped()
                , points.get(1).getXsnapped());
        System.out.format("(Note: epsilon is %f)%n"
                , points.get(0).getEps());

        assertEquals(points.get(0).getXsnapped()
                    , points.get(1).getXsnapped());
    }
}
```

**Output of JUnit Test**

```
testing xSnapped of two points: Point2 [x=0.5000, y=0.0000] and Point2 [x=0.5000, y=0.0000]
and they are 500 and 500 respectively
(Note: epsilon is 0.001000)
```

**Caveat**

Eric Duminil is correct in pointing out that there can be 
2 points arbitrarily close to one another, and still be snapped to different points on the grid.

Off the top of my head, I don't know how to solve this problem.  Suggestions 
are welcome!

E.g.

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    Point2 dummy = new Point2(0, 0);    // just to get epsilon
    points.add(new Point2(dummy.getEps()*0.5, 0));
    points.add(new Point2(dummy.getEps()*0.49999999999999, 0));
}
```

With these added debugging code:

```
public long getXsnapped() {
    boolean isDebug = true;
    String _ = "    "; // indent
    double X = this.getX();
    Util.debugPrint(isDebug, _ + "X is %E (long bits is 0x%x)%n"
                                , X, Double.doubleToLongBits(X));
    double eps = this.getEps();
    Util.debugPrint(isDebug, _ + "eps is %E%n", eps);
    double fraction = X/eps;
    Util.debugPrint(isDebug, _ + "fraction is %E (long bits is 0x%x)%n"
                                , fraction, Double.doubleToLongBits(fraction));
    long answer = Math.round(fraction); 
    Util.debugPrint(isDebug, _ + "xSnapped is %d%n", answer);
    return answer;
}
```

Util.debugPrint():

```
public static void debugPrint(boolean isDebug, String format, Object... args) {
    if (!isDebug) {
        return; // don't print
    }
    System.out.format(format, args);
}
```

I would get following output -- the two points are considered different!

```
testing xSnapped of two points: Point2 [x=0.0005, y=0.0000] and Point2 [x=0.0005, y=0.0000]
    X is 5.000000E-04 (long bits is 0x3f40624dd2f1a9fc)
    eps is 1.000000E-03
    fraction is 5.000000E-01 (long bits is 0x3fe0000000000000)
    xSnapped is 1
    X is 5.000000E-04 (long bits is 0x3f40624dd2f1a9a0)
    eps is 1.000000E-03
    fraction is 5.000000E-01 (long bits is 0x3fdfffffffffff4c)
    xSnapped is 0
and they are 1 and 0 respectively
(Note: epsilon is 0.001000)
delta between the two x (as double) is 9.974660E-18
    X is 5.000000E-04 (long bits is 0x3f40624dd2f1a9fc)
    eps is 1.000000E-03
    fraction is 5.000000E-01 (long bits is 0x3fe0000000000000)
    xSnapped is 1
    X is 5.000000E-04 (long bits is 0x3f40624dd2f1a9a0)
    eps is 1.000000E-03
    fraction is 5.000000E-01 (long bits is 0x3fdfffffffffff4c)
    xSnapped is 0
```

Comment: Sorry, no. That's a good point. I'll see if I can provide an updated answer later.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the requirement that the square may have to be rotatable.  I have updated my answer above.

Comment: Sorry, have you read my answer? You are proposing almost the same.

Comment: No I did not see you answer while working on my own.  Now that you pointed it out, I have read it, but I think our solutions are not the same.  My solution searches for points C, D, (and A) by turning the vector A->B by 90 degrees and so on.  My solution does not make use of the origin (0,0).  I think my solution is more intuitive (at least this is true for me), and the mathematical formulation would be simpler.

Comment: By the way, why do think your solution is O(n^2 lg(n))?  I think it is just O(n*2) -- for any given pair of points, you only need a constant time to compute C and D and a constant lookup time (if you store all the point in a hashmap) to see if C and D are among the set of points.

Comment: With your `getXsnapped()` definition, I think 2 points could be arbitrarily close to one another, and still be snapped to different points on the grid. e.g. `0.49999999` and `0.50000001`.

Comment: @Eric -- I am not sure what you said is true.  I just added a JUnit test case (and added it to my answer above).  I think my `Point2#getXsnapped()` behaves as expected -- that it turns an imprecise `double` coordinate into a precise `long` so that it will be safe for use in `equals()` and `hashCode()`

Comment: @leeyuiwah : Sorry, I picked a wrong example. `a=eps*0.5;` and `b=eps*0.49999999999999;`. `a` and `b` differ by `1E-17` but aren't snapped to the same point. I think that's where your `O(n**2)` comes from. Your algorithm will output false negatives.

Comment: @Eric -- You are right.  I added a caveat to my answer above.  Off the top of my head, I don't know of a good solution.  Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Nearest_neighbour_search or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree could help you.

Answer (score 5):

Take all pairs of points; for each pair calculate its angle, its length and the middle point.  This will take O(n^2) time.
For each set of pairs *having the same middle point and the same length* sort these pairs by angle, this will take in total O(n^2*log(n)) time.  This will help you to find two orthogonal diagonals of the same length having the same middle point (that is the square!).
Total algo time complexity is O(n^2*log(n)).

Comment: *This will help you to find two orthogonal diagonals of the same length having the same middle point* -- do you mean you can do it in lg(n) for every pair? Can you elaborate, please? For me it looks like lg(n^2).

Comment: @Yola - Just simultaneously move two pointers across this sorted list to search for two values having delta = pi/2.  This operation has linear time complexity

Comment: ah, sorry, i missed another part about sets of pairs *having the same middle point and the same length*. Though that is not clear how do you obtain such sets, what is the complexity of this operation? And what if you got only one such set (points on circle), then sorting would take O(n^2*lg(n^2)), right?

Comment: @Yola - Right, but O(n^2*lg(n^2)) = O(n^2*lg(n))

Comment: stupid me, so, only difference is space, ok, thanks for explanations, +1

Comment: @Yola - On real applications this algo would be faster, approximately O(n^2).  Use **hashing** to split pairs in sets "the same length and the same middle point".  Please note that calculating square of length and middle point could be done without loss of precision, so hashing is appropriate here.  Each set would consists of very few pairs.  The worst case you were talking about (points on circle) would result in O(n) pairs to be sorted, not O(n^2) pairs.  Of course, you need O(n^2) memory to run this algo.

Comment: You could probably explain what you mean by "the angle of a pair of points".

Comment: @EricDuminil - `(Math.atan2(y2-y1,x2-x1)+Math.PI)%Math.PI`

Answer (score 1):

Here is **O(n^2 lg(n))**-time and **O(n)**-space algorithm. If you will presort vertices by angle, then for every pair {A,B} you can find both angles OC and OD.

```
compute angle for every point -- O(n)
sort point by angles -- O(n*lg(n))
for each pair -- O(n^2*lg(n))
    if (B.x > A.x) && (B.y > A.y)
        compute positions of C and D
        compute angles of C and D
        for C and D
            if there is a pair of points with same angles and same positions
                return true
return false
```

[image]

How to find coordinates of C:

```
Xc = Xb - (Yb - Ya)
Yc = Yb + (Xb - Xa)
```